# Differentialy Fed Antenna Feeding Network

Tags: antenna, impedance, differential, passive-networks

I need help with the feeding line for the following scenario. I have a dipole-like antenna for which I need balancing the input, see picture (dipole antenna used just for illustration; it does not have correct dimensions). I am interested in measuring the input impedance of the antenna using the method from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/739191.

I have tried to construct a feeding network, as in the picture. I have used 100 Ohm differential pairs and then 50 Ohm coplanar waveguides to connect SMA connectors. Is this the correct approach?

[image]

Edit: terms in post corrected.

Comment: What does symmetrization mean in this context and, how does it apply to antennas? Maybe you mean symmetry as in "I need symmetry"?

Comment: I have noticed that "symmetrization" might be quite a local term used only in my country. I will replace it in the post. I am talking about transforming the balanced antenna feeding port. If you have a monopole fed with a coaxial cable, you connect the ground plane to the outer conductor and the monopole itself to the inner conductor. However, in the case of balanced antennas, you cannot do this directly because of leakage current flowing on the outer coax cable. I hope I expressed it more clearly now.

Comment: You can always use a balun: the unbalanced coax feed gets converted to a balanced drive to the dipole.

Comment: I am aware of that possibility. However, I would like to measure directly the impedance between antenna terminals. I am afraid that balun would distort the results and additional deembedding would be too demanding on resources.